# Change response based on query string in java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, query-string

Im having some trouble sending diffrenet response based on `query string`, I have 2 String that suppose to match a single param from the query names `serviceType`:

```
private static String restartQuery = "restarts";
private static String dbStatusQuery = "dbStatus";
```

And my `doGet` function needs to send response accordingly:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException{
    String requestType = request.getParameter(serviceType);
    // Set response content type
          response.setContentType("text/html");    
    if(requestType.equals(restartQuery)){
        //handle response for restartQuery
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("response for restart ....");
    }else if (requestType.equals(dbStatusQuery)){
        //handle response for dbStatusQuery
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("response for db ....");
        }
  }
```

The problem is that I get the same response(restart...), I had check the query string from the front-end - `system.println(requestType)` and they are different for each request, what can I change to make it work? if there is more code needed please comment below.

Comment: No, they are defined as static.

Comment: They should work as expected, I don't see any logical error here. Still you can try your luck by reverting the equals statements to restartQuery.equals(requestType) and dbStatusQuery.equals(requestType)

Comment: is it too late to recommend using jersey?

Comment: Check if the parameter values have got any spaces in `requestType` value?

Comment: I added final to the string and it work, I have no idea why....

Comment: @Bunti - No, there were no spaces, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have added 2 things based on comments here:

1- added consts to my defitions:

```
private static final String restartQuery = "restarts";
private static final String dbStatusQuery = "dbStatus";
```

2- check spaces from the front-end, just use a simple `prefix` check.

Thanks to all the helpers.